# Jmeter script waits for some time after clicking menu button

Tags: google-chrome, onclick, jmeter, click

I am clicking on a Menu Item which takes the user to a different page on the application. After clicking menu item , script waits for few seconds or more than a minute sometimes before moving ahead to the next step. There are no wait/delays etc after click and have verified from logs that it keeps waiting after clicking menu item and does not move ahead to the next line. This is the description of menuitem (using chrome sampler)

```
id="SummaryMenuItem" href="../AppsView/page.aspx?ViewID=cc1d569c-6f26-4a4f-bc64-86fb1fdbb236&amp;Layout=MarketData&amp;Theme=Default" onclick="addToNav('../AppsView/page.aspx?ViewID=cc1d569c-6f26-4a4f-bc64-86fb1fdbb236&amp;Layout=MarketData&amp;
```

My chrome sampler script

```
wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath('//div[@id=\'navMenuSubs\']//*[@id=\'SummaryMenuItem\']')))

var subMenu = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//div[@id=\'navMenuSubs\']//*[@id=\'SummaryMenuItem\']'))
subMenu.click();
```

Can anyone suggest why script keeps on waiting

Thanks

Comment: if it "keeps waiting after clicking menu item" then the code you posted is irrelevant...

Answer (score 0):

Usually clicks are not recorded in the jmeter but the request initiated by the click (click event-->request to the server) is getting recorded. If co-relation is not done properly then it may not proceed further.

If there is no request send due to click then nothing will be recorded.

Hope this helps.